# Не могу поменять местами элементы двумерного массива с помощью дополнительного вектора

Tags: c++, массивы

Не понимаю как поменять местами 2 столбец с 3-им рядом с помощью дополнительного вектора

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 100
#define M 100
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int rows = 0, columns = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество строк массива: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов массива: ";
    cin >> columns;

    int Array[N][M];
    cout << "Начальный массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            Array[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20;
            cout << Array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl;
   
    //Попытка поменять местами элементы без дополнительного вектора
    for (int i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; i++)
    {
        int tmp;
        tmp = Array[3][i];
        Array[3][i] = Array[i][2];
        Array[i][2] = tmp;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Преобразованный массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (rows == 3 || columns == 2) {
            cout << "Вы ввели слишком маленькое значение" << endl;
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << Array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код как то не правильно работает? Напишите как.

Comment: if (rows == 3 || columns == 2) нужно вынести из цикла и поместить до того как начнется обмен элементов местами, а также заменить на if (rows <= 3 || columns  <=2).  И непонятно, причем здесь вектор?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Здраствуйте мне нужно поменять местами 2-й столбец с 3-им рядом с помощью вектора, а в коде я попытался поменять элементы без помощи вектора

Comment: Пожалуйста объясните конкретней. Вы хотите например в вектор записать полностью 2-ой столбец, в другой вектор например 3-й ряд. И потом просто скопировать их элементы в матрицу но наоборот?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Да, все верно, нужно записать в вектор 2-й столбец и 3-й ряд и вывести преобразованный массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ну если я правильно все понял, то вот пример кода замены 3 ряда и 2 столбца между собой:

```
vector<int> row3(rows);
vector<int> col2(columns);

//Копируем 3 ряд
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    row3[i] = Array[2][i];

//Копируем 2 столбец
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    col2[i] = Array[i][1];

//Меняем местами
for (int i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; i++)
{
    Array[2][i] = col2[i];
    Array[i][1] = row3[i];
}
```

Так же @AlexeyVesker прав и вам нужно делать проверку на введенное кол-во строк и столбцов таким образом:

```
if (rows < 3 || columns < 2) {
    cout << "Вы ввели слишком маленькое значение" << endl;
    break;
}
```

А так же эту проверку поместить перед началом замены.

Самый простой способ вывести данные вектора это:

```
for(int i = 0; i < row3.size(); i++)
    cout << row3[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Ну откровенно говоря достаточно просто  If (rows < 3 || columns < 2), а в строках  Array[3][i]... и  Array[i][2]... цифры 3 и 2 заменить на 2 и 1 соответственно, т.к. элементы массива с нуля считаются. В текущей реализации меняем 4й ряд и 3 столбец ))). Сам тоже сначала маху дал)).

Comment: Ну это да, но я основывался на коде автора вопроса. Сейчас исправлю :)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Извините Павел, последний вопрос, как мне вывести на экран данные вектора?

Comment: @Anubis вообще как обычный массив. Я привел привет в ответе.